# Clipboard manager not opening for long press event of EditText,WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext, clipboardmanager, android-viewgroup

In one of my application i have `WebView` implemented to load some data from url. Everything is working perfect.

But whenever i am trying to long press and select the text of `WebView` an application gets crashed and throws error as below:
Even it throws error whenever i am trying to select text from `EditText` onLongPress event.

I am just not able to understand why its throwing such kind of error.

```
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarContextView can only be used with android:layout_width="match_parent" (or fill_parent)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.onMeasure(ActionBarContextView.java:397)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15679)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1433)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:720)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:593)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15679)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15679)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1433)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:720)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:593)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15679)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at com.ovte.slidemenu.widget.Phone_AnimationLayout.onMeasure(Phone_AnimationLayout.java:87)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15679)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1433)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:720)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:593)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15679)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15679)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1433)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:720)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:593)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15679)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15679)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2214)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1298)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1492)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1188)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4986)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5316)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-05 18:54:13.413: E/AndroidRuntime(29849):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have already tried suggestions from below sites:

[Illegal State exception on double clicking a edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530474/illegal-state-exception-on-double-clicking-a-edittext)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19021

[How to avoid a IllegalStateException: ActionBarContextView in older app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966250/how-to-avoid-a-illegalstateexception-actionbarcontextview-in-older-app)

[How to avoid a IllegalStateException: ActionBarContextView in older app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966250/how-to-avoid-a-illegalstateexception-actionbarcontextview-in-older-app)

Anyone can give me solution for this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found one solution that i have restricted the text being copy,paste using the `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()` method as below:

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Returning false from `onCreateActionMode(ActionMode, Menu)` will prevent the action mode from being started(Select All, Cut, Copy and Paste actions).